# Restangular - custom search - search within an array

Tags: json, angularjs, mongodb, restangular, mlab

Lets assume I have an mongodb `items` collection looking like this (MongoLab):

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "531d8dd2e4b0373ae7e8f505"
    },
     "tags": [
        "node",
        "json"
    ],
    "anotherField": "datahere"
}
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "531d8dd2e4b0373ae7e8f505"
    },
     "tags": [
        "ajax",
        "json"
    ],
    "anotherField": "datahere"
  }
```

I would like to get all items where a `node` is within the `tags` array. 
I've tried the below, but no success  - **it is returning all items** - no search performed?

Plunker demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/BYj09TOGyCTFKhhBXpIO?p=preview

```
// $route.current.params.id = "node" - should give me only 1 record with this tag
Restangular.all("items").customGET("", { "tags": $route.current.params.id });
```

Full example, return same record for both cases:

```
    var all = db.all('items');

    // GET ALL
    all.getList().then(function(data) {
        $scope.all = data;
        console.log(data);
    });

    // SEARCH for record where "tags" has got "node"
    all.customGET('', { "tags": "node"}).then(function(data) {
        $scope.search = data;
        console.log(data);
    });
```

Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Comment: you provided code which is not related with your problem... It seems a fine Restangular usage there... It should be related with your with server side... Can you provide your backend code?

Comment: @wickY26 - I am using a MongoLab as a back-end. So the problem must be with my `restangular search query`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Mongolab REST API Documentation](http://docs.mongolab.com/restapi/#list-documents) you have to pass the query object with the `q` parameter. In your case it is `q={"tags":"node"}`.

Using Restangular it will be like this:

`Restangular.all("items").customGET('', { q: {"tags": "node"}})`

Comment: good job... here is working plunker... http://plnkr.co/edit/pxVNyDmwECaoGeOc8PvS?p=preview

Comment: the plunkr link is dead